# serialization is not work properly in lower levels- django-rest-framework

Tags: django, recursion, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

my `Comment` model is like below:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='answers')
```

I want to serializer comment and all of its answers. So i've wrote this serializer:

```
class CommentSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(fields=('get_full_name',), allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['user', 'content', 'answers']
        depth = 10
```

now when I serialize a comment by this serializer, it works properly just for level 1 of the comment. the `answers` object shows all the data, such as user's password! or it shows 'parent' while I didn't include `parent` to the `fields` of `Meta` class of the serializer.
the following is the output of this serializer:

```
{
"data": {
    "pk": 15,
    "user": null,
    "name": "rwqerweqr",
    "email": null,
    "content": "A",
    "approved": false,
    "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:16:44.980338+04:30",
    "answers": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "content": "B",
            "name": null,
            "email": null,
            "approved": false,
            "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:08:13.374350+04:30",
            "user": {
                "id": 3,
                "is_superuser": true,
                "email": "email@gmail.com",
                "phone": "+111111111111",
                "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                "first_name": "Alex",
                "last_name": "Doe",
                "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_staff": true,
                "groups": [],
                "user_permissions": []
            },
            "parent": {
                "id": 15,
                "content": "A",
                "name": "rwqerweqr",
                "email": null,
                "approved": false,
                "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:16:44.980338+04:30",
                "user": null,
                "parent": {
                    "id": 13,
                    "content": "C",
                    "name": null,
                    "email": null,
                    "approved": false,
                    "created_at": "2019-03-31T21:27:29.152248+04:30",
                    "user": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "is_superuser": true,
                        "email": "email@gmail.com",
                        "phone": "+111111111111",
                        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                        "first_name": "Alex",
                        "last_name": "Doe",
                        "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                        "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "is_staff": true,
                        "groups": [],
                        "user_permissions": []
                    },
                    "parent": {
                        "id": 14,
                        "content": "B",
                        "name": null,
                        "email": null,
                        "approved": false,
                        "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:08:13.374350+04:30",
                        "user": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "is_superuser": true,
                            "email": "email@gmail.com",
                            "phone": "+111111111111",
                            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                            "first_name": "Alex",
                            "last_name": "Doe",
                            "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                            "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "is_staff": true,
                            "groups": [],
                            "user_permissions": []
                        },
                        "parent": {
                            "id": 15,
                            "content": "A",
                            "name": "rwqerweqr",
                            "email": null,
                            "approved": false,
                            "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:16:44.980338+04:30",
                            "user": null,
                            "parent": {
                                "id": 13,
                                "content": "C",
                                "name": null,
                                "email": null,
                                "approved": false,
                                "created_at": "2019-03-31T21:27:29.152248+04:30",
                                "user": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "is_superuser": true,
                                    "email": "email@gmail.com",
                                    "phone": "+111111111111",
                                    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                                    "first_name": "Alex",
                                    "last_name": "Doe",
                                    "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                                    "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                                    "is_active": true,
                                    "is_staff": true,
                                    "groups": [],
                                    "user_permissions": []
                                },
                                "parent": {
                                    "id": 14,
                                    "content": "B",
                                    "name": null,
                                    "email": null,
                                    "approved": false,
                                    "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:08:13.374350+04:30",
                                    "user": {
                                        "id": 3,
                                        "is_superuser": true,
                                        "email": "email@gmail.com",
                                        "phone": "+111111111111",
                                        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                                        "first_name": "Alex",
                                        "last_name": "Doe",
                                        "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                                        "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                                        "is_active": true,
                                        "is_staff": true,
                                        "groups": [],
                                        "user_permissions": []
                                    },
                                    "parent": {
                                        "id": 15,
                                        "content": "A",
                                        "name": "rwqerweqr",
                                        "email": null,
                                        "approved": false,
                                        "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:16:44.980338+04:30",
                                        "user": null,
                                        "parent": {
                                            "id": 13,
                                            "content": "C",
                                            "name": null,
                                            "email": null,
                                            "approved": false,
                                            "created_at": "2019-03-31T21:27:29.152248+04:30",
                                            "user": {
                                                "id": 3,
                                                "is_superuser": true,
                                                "email": "email@gmail.com",
                                                "phone": "+111111111111",
                                                "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                                                "first_name": "Alex",
                                                "last_name": "Doe",
                                                "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                                                "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                                                "is_active": true,
                                                "is_staff": true,
                                                "groups": [],
                                                "user_permissions": []
                                            },
                                            "parent": {
                                                "id": 14,
                                                "content": "B",
                                                "name": null,
                                                "email": null,
                                                "approved": false,
                                                "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:08:13.374350+04:30",
                                                "user": 3,
                                                "parent": 15
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "content": "D",
            "name": "werwer",
            "email": null,
            "approved": false,
            "created_at": "2019-04-01T18:37:46.981327+04:30",
            "user": null,
            "parent": {
                "id": 15,
                "content": "A",
                "name": "rwqerweqr",
                "email": null,
                "approved": false,
                "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:16:44.980338+04:30",
                "user": null,
                "parent": {
                    "id": 13,
                    "content": "C",
                    "name": null,
                    "email": null,
                    "approved": false,
                    "created_at": "2019-03-31T21:27:29.152248+04:30",
                    "user": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "is_superuser": true,
                        "email": "email@gmail.com",
                        "phone": "+111111111111",
                        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                        "first_name": "Alex",
                        "last_name": "Doe",
                        "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                        "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "is_staff": true,
                        "groups": [],
                        "user_permissions": []
                    },
                    "parent": {
                        "id": 14,
                        "content": "B",
                        "name": null,
                        "email": null,
                        "approved": false,
                        "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:08:13.374350+04:30",
                        "user": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "is_superuser": true,
                            "email": "email@gmail.com",
                            "phone": "+111111111111",
                            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                            "first_name": "Alex",
                            "last_name": "Doe",
                            "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                            "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "is_staff": true,
                            "groups": [],
                            "user_permissions": []
                        },
                        "parent": {
                            "id": 15,
                            "content": "A",
                            "name": "rwqerweqr",
                            "email": null,
                            "approved": false,
                            "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:16:44.980338+04:30",
                            "user": null,
                            "parent": {
                                "id": 13,
                                "content": "C",
                                "name": null,
                                "email": null,
                                "approved": false,
                                "created_at": "2019-03-31T21:27:29.152248+04:30",
                                "user": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "is_superuser": true,
                                    "email": "email@gmail.com",
                                    "phone": "+111111111111",
                                    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                                    "first_name": "Alex",
                                    "last_name": "Doe",
                                    "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                                    "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                                    "is_active": true,
                                    "is_staff": true,
                                    "groups": [],
                                    "user_permissions": []
                                },
                                "parent": {
                                    "id": 14,
                                    "content": "B",
                                    "name": null,
                                    "email": null,
                                    "approved": false,
                                    "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:08:13.374350+04:30",
                                    "user": {
                                        "id": 3,
                                        "is_superuser": true,
                                        "email": "email@gmail.com",
                                        "phone": "+111111111111",
                                        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                                        "first_name": "Alex",
                                        "last_name": "Doe",
                                        "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                                        "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                                        "is_active": true,
                                        "is_staff": true,
                                        "groups": [],
                                        "user_permissions": []
                                    },
                                    "parent": {
                                        "id": 15,
                                        "content": "A",
                                        "name": "rwqerweqr",
                                        "email": null,
                                        "approved": false,
                                        "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:16:44.980338+04:30",
                                        "user": null,
                                        "parent": {
                                            "id": 13,
                                            "content": "C",
                                            "name": null,
                                            "email": null,
                                            "approved": false,
                                            "created_at": "2019-03-31T21:27:29.152248+04:30",
                                            "user": {
                                                "id": 3,
                                                "is_superuser": true,
                                                "email": "email@gmail.com",
                                                "phone": "+111111111111",
                                                "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$RDdFKTXhvzhb$GaR2Y0p1DBp/5pO5yqayMmdNN/XjnoWEdKshYbmkwCk=",
                                                "first_name": "Alex",
                                                "last_name": "Doe",
                                                "created_at": "2019-03-26T21:16:53.818407+04:30",
                                                "last_login": "2019-03-26T21:17:14.987512+04:30",
                                                "is_active": true,
                                                "is_staff": true,
                                                "groups": [],
                                                "user_permissions": []
                                            },
                                            "parent": {
                                                "id": 14,
                                                "content": "B",
                                                "name": null,
                                                "email": null,
                                                "approved": false,
                                                "created_at": "2019-03-31T23:08:13.374350+04:30",
                                                "user": 3,
                                                "parent": 15
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

as you see, in the `answers` object, it shows user's data completely, include of its hashed password or permissions.
or it shows `parent` field while it is not in the serializer at all!.

how to solve this problem?
thanks.

**UPDATE**
usecase: Comments B and D are answers of comment A. (b.parent == A)

Answer (score 0):

As displayed in `django-rest-framework` docs:

> The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a flat representation.
>
> If you want to customize the way the serialization is done you'll need to define the field yourself.

You should serialize the `answers` field, in order to hide those informations. I would follow the approach of `SerializerMethodField`. I will write an example:

```
class CommentSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(fields=('get_full_name',), allow_null=True)
    answers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['user', 'content', 'answers']

    def get_answers(self, instance):
        # Here you will create your custom serialization
```